# Part of the image clickable in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I don't know whether this is the right place to ask this question.

I have an image when I am displaying in a UIImageView. This image view takes the full screen. In the image there are facebook, twitter and email buttons (not actually buttons - it's designed in the image).

I want to make the facebook, twitter and email "buttons" tappable and do something. Is this possible?

Comment: Two ways:  1) use touchesEnded as described by reecon and locate the touches by "dead reckoning".  2) position transparent buttons over the image and use them like any other button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing it the right way.

Most of the time when you make an interface there's a lot of logical components, and each components has its own actions (animation/tappable/editable components). For each different logical component you should put a different element on it.

In your case, I would set up a full screen `UIImageView` just for the background, add `UILabel`s for the texts on it (you can opt-out on this if your text won't have any effect on it, but that's what I prefer because this way it's more flexible in the future). And on top of those, you can add `UIButton`s for the tappable elements, for example, Facebook and twitter buttons.

---

Edit: If you just hate making separate images, you can always make invisible buttons (a button without any text)

Comment: Ok. This sounds good. So I make one image for the background image and separate images for the buttons and use UIButtons.

Comment: @Siddharth Yes. This is what I do and I believe is what everyone else is doing. Considering the rumor (or fact) that Apple is making a third screen size, having those elements separate can make your life a lot easier when adapting for different screens.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `touchesEnded:withEvent:` method and check if the touch location is within the rectangle of a desired button in the image.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
  [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(_facebookButtonRect, location))
    {
        // Do your stuff.
    }
}
```

You can also place invisible buttons on top of the image view.

Comment: How to determine the `_facebookButtonRect`or `_twitterButtonRect` ? All the buttons are part of the same image and are not loaded as separate images.

Answer (score 0):

For each button:

1) Add a transparent `UIButton` as a subview to your image view. Position it on your image by setting its frame. Use `alpha=1` and `backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]` for the button. Also set the button title to "". All this should give you an invisible button that still responds to touches.

2) Handle the button tap event as usual.